# MySQL: find full table scan queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Using MySQL 5.6.24.

What is the best way to extract the text of queries using full-table scans? The "Full Table Scans" report in MySQL Workbench doesn't include the complete query (some text is replaced with ...), for example:

```
SELECT `Db` AS `scope` , SYSTE ... sql` . `db` WHERE ? LIKE `db`
```

I also tried querying the sys database directly but the same limitations exist there:

```
select * from sys.`statements_with_full_table_scans`
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A "full table scan" is not necessarily evil.  Nor is it always avoidable.  I would focus on whatever is "slow" in the slowlog.  _Some_ of them will involve full table scans; _some_ full table scans won't be slow enough to show up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries that do "full table scan" are the ones that don't use indexes. Try to log them in the slow query log using this option [log_queries_not_using_indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_queries_not_using_indexes)

Be careful though that small tables that have frequent queries running against will fill your slow query log files. You may want to enable this option for limited amount of time. To reduce this chance, you may set [min_examined_row_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_min-examined-row-limit) variable to a reasonable value, depending on your small tables.

Comment: Hi. So, "full table scan" is not the opposite of ones "that don't use indexes". We have a situation where some queries that are holding things up ARE using some indexes, but the problem is they are ALSO doing table scans. And there is no MySQL setting that finds these. I know of a bad query that is doing a table scan as well as indexes and it does not show up in this log with that setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use view with full query

```
select query, exec_count
from sys.x$statements_with_full_table_scans
```